# Laravel 5.1 User Registration does not work

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Goodday!

I recently created a new laravel 5.1 application and try not to get the whole authentication thing done.

I have done the routes and the view as in this reference: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authentication-quickstart

My problem now is, that I cannot create any user with this all standard default solution. I didn't touch the AuthController except that I added a $redirectPath variable. I checked the DB connection which is fine.

Any help is highly appreciated!
Please tell me if you need further information.

Comment: What happens when you attempt to register? Do you get any error messages? Are there any errors in your logs?

Comment: there are no errors or anything else in the logs. the POST is sent and i just found out, that there is a postRegister method in the "Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers" class which is used by the AuthController, but it seems not to create the user, although i think it should

Answer (score 0):

the mentioned method looks like this:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

after investigating this, i recognized, that the validator which is in the AuthController failed. Unfortunately, there was no log message or info in the browser to inform about that.

This is what I am gonna implement now.